# How to save web page content to a text file

Tags: dom, browser, vbscript

I use an automation script that tests a browser-based application. I'd like to save the visible text of each page I load as a text file. This needs to work for the current open browser window. I've come across some solutions that use `InternetExplorer.Application` but this won't work for me as it has to be the current open page.

Ideally, I'd like to achieve this using vbscript.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: WSH `Shell .Exec/.AppActivate/.SendKeys` methods should do the job.

Comment: Do not use `SendKeys` if you can possibly avoid it. It's a *really* unreliable way of handling things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach to an already running IE instance like this:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each window In app.Windows()
  If InStr(1, window.FullName, "iexplore", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set ie = window
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Then save the document body text like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True)
f.Write ie.document.body.innerText
f.Close
```

If the page contains non-ASCII characters you may need to create the output file with Unicode encoding:

```
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True, -1)
```

or save it as UTF-8:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type     = 2 'text
stream.Position = 0
stream.Charset  = "utf-8"
stream.WriteText ie.document.body.innerText
stream.SaveToFile "output.txt", 2
stream.Close
```

---

**Edit:** Something like this may help getting rid of script code in the document body:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = "<script[\s\S]*?</script>"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global     = True

ie.document.body.innerHtml = re.Replace(ie.document.body.innerHtml, "")

WScript.Echo ie.document.body.innerText
```

Comment: Yes, good catch (+1). Only one note - if I use `OpenTextFile` with default (open as ASCII) then a bad procedure call error appear on `.Write` call. Open as Unicode works, ie `fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True, -1)`.

Comment: Thanks Angsar, that's what I was looking for. The only slight problem is that the output text file contains a lot of script code in addition to the text. Any way to get a clearer output? Thanks for your time. J.

Comment: Thanks very much Ansgar, that helped hugely.

Comment: One last thing. I noticed that after I run the script, the page elements on Internet Explorer are disabled. I have to close and re-open the browser to get them working again. I destroyed all objects but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @bearaman That might be because the script elements were removed.